# Relative path for a file accesed from Java resource directory file

Tags: java, xslt, glassfish, payara

I have an `example.xsl File` in Java resource directory that is accessed in Java through:

```java
class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.xsl");
```

But the `example.xsl File` itself has a reference:

```xml
<xsl:include href="dir/i18n.inc.xslt"/>
```

I want to put the `dir directory` with `i18n.inc.xslt` inside the resource directory, however it seems like that when I deploy the code, the program is looking for `dir/i18n.inc.xslt` inside `glassfish/domains/domain1/config`.

How should I refer to `dir/i18n.inc.xslt` in `href` so that it will look inside resources?

**Edit:**
I use `Java 17` and `Payara 6`. XSLT is used to convert XML into PDF. I am using `Apache FOP` for this purpose.

```java
InputStream  styleSheetInput = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.xsl");

            final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

            try {
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, outputStream);
                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(styleSheetInput));

                // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Source src = new StreamSource(datafile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                transformer.transform(src, res);
           }
```

**The Exception I get:**

```
 [tid: _ThreadID=279 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool11] [timeMillis: 1693598088423] [levelVal
  /usr/local/payara6/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/dir/i18n.inc.xslt (No such file or directory)]]
```

So it seems it is looking inside config directory as a base directory. But I do not to put the `XSLT File` there. I put it in the same place as `example.xsl` in resources.

Comment: You need to explain what you are using to process the resource. What bit of software is handling the `<xsl:include`? Please edit your question to include the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

At the end the problem was resolved by setting systemId in Source for Transformer.

```
String sysId = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("example.xsl").toURI().toString();
InputStream  styleSheetInput = this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.xsl");
...
Source mySrc = new StreamSource(styleSheetInput);
mySrc.setSystemId(sysId);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(mySrc);
```

I also renamed `i18n.inc.xslt` into `i18n.inc.xsl` otherwise it would not get into `WEB-INF/classes` for some reason.